# How to easily make a large number of polymorphic assignments?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Currently this is how I do my polymorphic assignments, manually, one by one:

Eg:

```
employees[ 0 ] = new salariedEmployee();
employees[ 1 ] = new salariedEmployee();
employees[ 2 ] = new commissionEmployee();
employees[ 3 ] = new hourlyEmployee();
```

How do you assign it more efficiently? Let's say you have to make 20 assignments?

Comment: There's no easier way. Maybe try `Employee[] employees = {new salariedEmployee(), new salariedEmployee(), new commissionEmployee(), new hourlyEmployee()};`

Comment: You can do that in a loop with some conditions. What decides what object is assigned to which index?

Comment: As long as you have to map one specific index to one specific class, theres no way to automate that.

Comment: @Amongalen, as long as it makes the assignments easier, anything is fine.

Comment: @ernest_k if its 20 assignments, that wont be easy

Comment: @HelloWorld It won't. But you're solving the wrong problem here. Assigning a 20-element array with select subtypes per index isn't exactly a clean problem to solve. You may want to map indices to types if you'd rather use something like a loop...

Comment: @HelloWorld of course that would be easy. Just write down 20 assignments, that takes less than a minute.

Comment: @ernest_k, the loop seems to be the best idea as I don't need to map it

Comment: @f1sh i was just giving an arbituary number, it could be 100 i guess

Comment: @HelloWorld and how do you tell your loop which class goes to which index? What rule is there?

Comment: @f1sh, there is no rule, I was think of using a for loop like `for(int i=0...)` and then using conditions like `if(i%2)//assign this subclass` and `if(i%3)//assign another subclass` and so on. Basically i just want them assigned in anyway that doesn't require you to write one by one

Comment: but those are rules :D If you stated them in your question, everyone would have suggested a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
employee[] employees = {
    new salariedEmployee(),
    new salariedEmployee(),
    new commissionEmployee(),
    new hourlyEmployee(),
};
```

Comment: I gave 4 assignments as an example it could be 20, 55 or something else. So far, a loop seems to be in comparison, the "best"